# How to import a text file to SAS Studio containing SQL create and insert statements of a database?

Tags: sql, import, sas, sas-studio

I'm completely new to SAS Studio.
I have a text file including SQL create statements and insert statements of a database, I need to import all data from this document to SAS studio to run the queries in asked in my assignment.
Part of my document looks:

```
create table Aschema.JOB(
JOB_ID num,
JOB_DESCRIPTION varchar(30),
JOB_CHARG_HOUR num(4,2),
constraint pkjob1 primary key (JOB_ID)
);

insert into Aschema.job
values (500,'Programmer',35.75)
values (502,'Database Designer',105.00)
values (505,'Civil Engineer',55.78)
values (507,'DSS Analyst',45.95)
values (504,'Mechanical Engineer',67.90);
```

I'm using the online one:

> https://odamid-apse1.oda.sas.com/SASODAControlCenter/

First I need to create a new library, then import this file to SAS studio.
Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to use that SQL code to create SAS datasets? Or pass it to some remote database system where it makes sense to try to use features like `CONSTRAINT` and data types like `NUM(4,2)`?  Is the code too long to just open it in the program editor?

Answer (score 0):

Create a libname and then wrap your code in PROC SQL. 
This was tested on SAS Academics on Demand and worked.

```
libname mylib '/home/xxxxxx/Sample';

proc sql;
create table mylib.JOB(
JOB_ID num,
JOB_DESCRIPTION varchar(30),
JOB_CHARG_HOUR num(4,2),
constraint pkjob1 primary key (JOB_ID)
);

insert into mylib.job
values (500,'Programmer',35.75)
values (502,'Database Designer',105.00)
values (505,'Civil Engineer',55.78)
values (507,'DSS Analyst',45.95)
values (504,'Mechanical Engineer',67.90);

quit;
```